# Python: json_normalize a pandas series gives TypeError

Tags: python, json, pandas, attributeerror, normalize

I have tens of thousands rows of json snippets like this in a pandas series `df["json"]`

```
[{
    'IDs': [{
        'lotId': '1',
        'Id': '123456'
    }],
    'date': '2009-04-17',
    'bidsCount': 2,
}, {
    'IDs': [{
        'lotId': '2',
        'Id': '123456'
    }],
    'date': '2009-04-17',
    'bidsCount': 4,
}, {
    'IDs': [{
         'lotId': '3',
         'Id': '123456'
    }],
    'date': '2009-04-17',
    'bidsCount': 8,
}]
```

Sample of the original file:

```
{"type": "OPEN","title": "rainbow","json": [{"IDs": [{"lotId": "1","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 2,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "2","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 4,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "3","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 8,}]}
{"type": "CLOSED","title": "clouds","json": [{"IDs": [{"lotId": "1","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 2,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "2","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 4,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "3","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 8,}]}


df = pd.read_json("file.json", lines=True)
```

I am trying to make them into a data frame, something like

```
Id      lotId      bidsCount    date
123456  1          2            2009-04-17
123456  2          4            2009-04-17
123456  3          8            2009-04-17
```

by using

`json_normalize(df["json"])`

However I get

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

I guess the json snippet is seen as a list, however I can not figure out how to make it work otherwise.
Help appreciated!

Comment: How do you create `df` first?

Comment: Please paste your data frame's head here. Is your `jsons` column a string?

Comment: zufanka first of all as the documentation says, the df['jsons'] should be a dict or list of dict. Then you could do `result = json_normalize(data, 'IDs', ['date', 'bidsCount'])` like this to get your desired result. I did same in my answer, don't know why people like to downvote. hope this helps

Comment: I create the df from an enormous json file through `pd.read_json("file.json", lines=True)` . The `json` column is one of the files nested parts, not a string. I can try to recreate the file, as the data is confidential if that would help.

Comment: zufanka, yes. just to type(df['json']) to make sure that its a dict, or list of dict to work with json_normalize(). If you could tell how you're creating the df['json'] then it would help. You don't need to recreate the whole data just a sample would be great.

Comment: `type(test['lots'])` is a `pandas.core.series.Series`,  `type(test['lots'][0])` is a `list` (the first element of the Series). It took some time, but here is a sample: https://pastebin.com/DAngCvKu

Comment: @zufanka did the answer help?

Comment: @Bharathshetty thank you, I am looking into it right now! I am namely creating a whole new huge dataframe from the json dataframe, I think a for loop should work, I just need to figure out how.

Comment: @zufanka Updated the answer based on your json data. Hope it helps

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your `df['json']` is a nested list. You can use a for loop and concatenate the dataframe to get the big dataframe i.e

Data:

```
{"type": "OPEN","title": "rainbow","json": [{"IDs": [{"lotId": "1","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 2,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "2","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 4,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "3","Id": "123456"}],"date": "2009-04-17","bidsCount": 8,}]}
{"type": "CLOSED","title": "clouds","json": [{"IDs": [{"lotId": "1","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 2,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "2","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 4,}, {"IDs": [{"lotId": "3","Id": "23345"}],"date": "2009-05-17","bidsCount": 8,}]}

df = pd.read_json("file.json", lines=True)
```

DataFrame:

```
new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(x)) for x in df['json']],ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
                                IDs  bidsCount        date
0  [{'Id': '123456', 'lotId': '1'}]          2  2009-04-17
1  [{'Id': '123456', 'lotId': '2'}]          4  2009-04-17
2  [{'Id': '123456', 'lotId': '3'}]          8  2009-04-17
3   [{'Id': '23345', 'lotId': '1'}]          2  2009-05-17
4   [{'Id': '23345', 'lotId': '2'}]          4  2009-05-17
5   [{'Id': '23345', 'lotId': '3'}]          8  2009-05-17
```

If you want the keys of IDs as columns then you use

```
new_df['lotId'] = [x[0]['lotId'] for x in new_df['IDs']]
new_df['IDs'] = [x[0]['Id'] for x in new_df['IDs']]
```

```
      IDs  bidsCount        date lotId
0  123456          2  2009-04-17     1
1  123456          4  2009-04-17     2
2  123456          8  2009-04-17     3
3   23345          2  2009-05-17     1
4   23345          4  2009-05-17     2
5   23345          8  2009-05-17     3
```

Comment: does exactly what I need, many thanks! Just needed to add `df['json'].dropna()` as some of the data is missing.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Any more efficient approaches to this?